# Best solution for acronyms, abbreviations, glossary and index

Tags: glossaries, indexing, acronyms

I am writing a scientific text/book which will contain acronyms, which should have a glossary and should also have an index. The question is: which LaTeX setup is best for this? Which are the best packages, etc.

Obviously, some of the problems are overlapping.

- I want to have a glossary where I explain some terms or where I give a one-sentence explanation and refer to the section where the term is discussed in detail.
- For some of these terms, it might be common to use the acronym/abbreviation. Examples are HTTP, TCP or Dow Jones.
- Other terms are usually written out, but I might want to use an abbreviation (in some sections) because they appear often or because they are so lengthy. (Examples: Distributed Event-Based System: DEBS or Peer-to-Peer: P2P)
- I want to have a List of Abbreviations and Acronyms.
- I also want to have a Glossary where some of the acronyms/abbreviations appear, but not all.
- I also want to have an index that links to the relevant pages where some of the index terms appear. It should also be possible for the index to contain terms that do not appear in the glossary or acronym list.

Searching for possibilities to achieve this I found several partial solutions, but I am not sure how they will work together, especially since some seem to overlap.

- [`acronym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package

  - seems to be quite common and powerful when it comes to acronyms
  - maybe even a little overkill.
  - unclear how to make use of it for index/glossary purposes
- [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package

  - supports glossaries nicely
  - also supports acronyms. But how can I define acronyms that should not appear in the glossary, but some should appear in the glossary
  - seems to work well with hyperref
  - uses makeindex
- index with `makeindex`, `\index{..}` and `\printindex`

  - is built-in in LaTeX
  - can I combine it with the glossaries package?
- other glossary packages like `makeglos`, `gloss`, `glossary`, `glosstex`
- other acronym packages like `nomencl`
- other index packages like `makeidx`

So there are many solutions, but which is the best?

Comment: And `imakeidx` and `acro` etc. And some other packages ... and my opinion based answer: Use `glossaries`, it provides all in one.

Comment: glossaries seems to be be most promissing. But it does not create an index (as far as I can tell). The index could be done with the build-in tools, but will they behave well, since both will use `makeindex`?

Comment: As far as I know it does create an index -- it uses index in the background anyway

Comment: `glossaries` can also be used for indexing, although that's less common than using `glossaries` and another indexing package, such as `makeidx` or `imakeidx`. If you use the `index` package option, `glossaries` enables the command `\newterm` which is essentially the same as `\newglossaryentry` except that it automatically sets the description to nothing and creates a new "glossary" for the index.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I think, you should provide the answer ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Okay. I'll sort out some examples.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> - I want to have a glossary where I explain some terms or where I give a one sentence explanation and refer to the section where the
>     term is discussed in detail.

With the `glossaries` package, each term is first defined (in the preamble if you don't want nasty surprises that can occur in certain circumstances) using `\newglossaryentry`. For example:

```
\newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,
  description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

\newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,
  description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}
```

(Make sure you use braces `{ }` around the values if they contain a comma `,` or equal sign `=`.)

The first argument is a label (avoid special characters) so that you can reference the term in the document text. For example:

```
A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.
```

Use `\printglossaries` where you want all the glossaries, lists of abbreviations etc to occur. These are displayed in order that each type of glossary was defined (the default `main` is usually first), but if you want to change the ordering or have some in the front matter and some in the back matter you'll need to use `\printglossary` and specify the type in the optional argument.

Complete minimal example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,%
  description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

\newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,%
  description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}


\begin{document}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The comments at the start are [`arara`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arara) directives. If you don't use `arara`, you can remove those lines. If you do use `arara`, then you can build the complete document using `arara myDoc` where the document is in the file `myDoc.tex`. If you're not using `arara`, you can build the document using

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The `makeglossaries` application is actually a Perl script, so you'll need Perl installed if you want to use it. If you don't have Perl installed, you can use a Lua alternative instead:

```
makeglossaries-lite myDoc
```

(The advantage of `makeglossaries` is that it has some diagnostic tools to check for common problems.) This Lua script is actually distributed with the filename `makeglossaries-lite.lua` but the TeX distributions usually arrange it so that you don't use the `.lua` extension.

For help integrating `makeglossaries` or `makeglossaries-lite` into your document build process, see [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries).

If you're still stuck, another possibility is to use the `automake` package option:

```
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
```

This just requires two LaTeX calls for the above example. Note that you can't use this if the shell escape has been disabled. (For a large document, it's more efficient to just call `makeglossaries` or `makeglossaries-lite` when the glossaries need updating rather than use `automake` which tries to rebuild them on every LaTeX run.)

The above example produces:

[image: A duck and a parrot. Lots of ducks. Glossary duck a waterbird with webbed feet. 1 parrot mainly tropical bird with bright plumage. 1]

The number `1` that appears after the description is the page number where the term was referenced. You can change the counter used with the `counter` package option. For example, to switch to the `section` counter:

```
\usepackage[counter=section]{glossaries}
```

or you can completely omit the number lists using the `nonumberlist` package option.

If you're really stuck and you're happy to omit the location numbers and do the sorting manually, then you can use `\printunsrtglossary` (or `\printunsrtglossaries`) provided by [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,%
  description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

\newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,%
  description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}

\begin{document}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

In this case the entries must be defined in the preamble (or using the package option `docdefs=restricted` they can be defined in the document anywhere *before* they are referenced and before the glossary). This method doesn't perform any indexing and simply iterates over all defined entries (so they must be defined first) in the order in which they were defined. There's no check to determine if the entries have actually been used in the document.

[image: A duck and a parrot. Lots of ducks. Glossary duck a waterbird with webbed feet parrot mainly tropical bird with bright plumage]

Note that the sentence terminating dot hasn't been automatically inserted after the description in this case. With `glossaries-extra` you need to use the package option `postdot` or `nopostdot=false` to add it.

The `sort=none` option may be omitted (`\printunsrtglossary` is always according to definition) but this option prevents the automated assignment of the `sort` field, which isn't required in this case. (It's not significant for such a small example.)

An alternative approach is to use [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) with [`bib2gls`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). This requires entries to be defined in `.bib` files, which means that if you have a large set of terms that you commonly use in your documents then you can use a `.bib` management system like [JabRef](http://ctan.org/pkg/jabref) to organise your definitions. (Both `bib2gls` and JabRef require Java.)

For example, the file `entries.bib` might contain:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@entry{duck,
  name = {duck},
  description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
}

@entry{parrot,
  name = {parrot},
  description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
}
```

(I can create this `entries.bib` file from my earlier `myDoc.tex` file using `convertgls2bib myDoc.tex entries.bib` which searches for commands like `\newglossaryentry` and converts them to the require `.bib` format.)

I now need to edit `myDoc.tex` to become:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]

\begin{document}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

The build process is now:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

If letter groups are required then you need `--group` (or `-g`):

```
bib2gls --group myDoc
```

and a glossary style that supports groups. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,style=indexgroup]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]

\begin{document}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: A duck and a parrot. Lots of ducks. Glossary D duck a waterbird with webbed feet 1 P parrot mainly tropical bird with bright plumage 1]

> - For some of these terms it might be common to use the acronym/abbreviation. Examples are HTTP, TCP or Dow Jones.
> - Other terms are usually written out, but I might want to use an abbreviation (in some sections) because they appear often or because they are so lengthy. (Examples: Distributed Event-Based System: DEBS or Peer-to-Peer: P2P)
> - I want to have a List of Abbreviations and Acronyms.

Abbreviations and acronyms can be defined with `\newacronym`. This internally uses `\newglossaryentry` and assigns a long and short form. The first argument is optional and can be used to provide additional fields for the second argument of `\newglossaryentry`. With just the base `glossaries` package, you can set the style using `\setacronymstyle` but this needs to be done before you define the terms. If you want a separate list of acronyms/abbreviations you can use the `acronym` package option. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,
  description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

\newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,
  description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newacronym{debs}{DEBS}{Distributed Event-Based System}
\newacronym{p2p}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}

\begin{document}
\section{Sample}

First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}. Next use: \gls{debs} and
\gls{p2p}.

\section{Another Sample}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Note that this expands on first use and uses the abbreviated form on subsequent use. (You can reset this if required.)

For abbreviations that shouldn't be expanded, there are three approaches:

1. Define them with `\newacronym` and then unset them (which pretends they have already been used):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

   \makeglossaries

   \newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,
     description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

   \newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,
     description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}

   \setacronymstyle{long-short}

   \newacronym{debs}{DEBS}{Distributed Event-Based System}
   \newacronym{p2p}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}

   \newacronym{http}{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}
   \glsunset{http}

   \begin{document}
   \section{Sample}

   First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}. Next use: \gls{debs} and
   \gls{p2p}.

   No expansion: \gls{http}.

   \section{Another Sample}

   A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

   \printglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Define them as a regular term but use the `type` key to put them in the list of abbreviations/acronyms:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

   \makeglossaries

   \newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,
     description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

   \newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,
     description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}

   \setacronymstyle{long-short}

   \newacronym{debs}{DEBS}{Distributed Event-Based System}
   \newacronym{p2p}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}

   \newglossaryentry{http}{name=HTTP,
    type=\acronymtype,
    description={Hypertext Transfer Protocol}}

   \begin{document}
   \section{Sample}

   First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}. Next use: \gls{debs} and
   \gls{p2p}.

   No expansion: \gls{http}.

   \section{Another Sample}

   A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

   \printglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Use the extension package [glossaries-extra](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), which allows different abbreviation styles. This package provides `\newabbreviation` to define an abbreviation with the entry's `category` (a new key provided by `glossaries-extra`) set to `abbreviation` and redefines `glossaries`'s `\newacronym` to use `\newabbreviation` with the `category` set to `acronym` (and the `type` set to `\acronymtype`). The abbreviation style is set using `\setabbreviationstyle[`*category*`]{`*style*`}` (not `\setacronymstyle`). The default style for the `abbreviation` category is `long-short` and the default style for the `acronym` category is `short`, so we can just use `\newabbreviation` for the abbreviations that need expansion on first use and `\newacronym` for abbreviations that don't need expansion on first use.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

   \makeglossaries

   \newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,
     description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

   \newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,
     description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}

   \newabbreviation{debs}{DEBS}{Distributed Event-Based System}
   \newabbreviation{p2p}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}

   \newacronym{http}{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}

   \begin{document}
   \section{Sample}

   First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}. Next use: \gls{debs} and
   \gls{p2p}.

   No expansion: \gls{http}.

   \section{Another Sample}

   A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

   \printglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```
4. With `bib2gls`, the earlier `entries.bib` supplies the terms (duck and parrot) and the abbreviations can be stored in another `.bib` file called, say, `abbrvs.bib`:

   ```
   % Encoding: UTF-8
   @abbreviation{debs,
     short = {DEBS},
     long = {Distributed Event-Based System}
   }

   @abbreviation{p2p,
     short = {P2P},
     long = {Peer-to-Peer}
   }
   ```

   and the common abbreviation in `common.bib`:

   ```
   % Encoding: UTF-8 
   @acronym{http,
     short = {HTTP},
     long = {Hypertext Transfer Protocol}
   }
   ```

   (or they can be combined in the same file). The document is now:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[record,abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

   \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]

   \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={abbrvs,common}]

   \begin{document}
   \section{Sample}

   First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}. Next use: \gls{debs} and
   \gls{p2p}.

   No expansion: \gls{http}.

   \section{Another Sample}

   A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

   \printunsrtglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```

The first two examples both produce:

[image: image of document]

The third and fourth examples produce:

[image: image of document]

The only differences here are the missing post-description dot (which can be added with `postdot`) and the title of the list of abbreviations. This is because I used the `abbreviations` package option. If I'd used `acronym` (or `acronyms`) instead, I would have to add the line

```
\renewcommand{\glsxtrabbrvtype}{\acronymtype}
```

to ensure the abbreviations defined using `\newabbreviation` are placed in the `acronym` glossary (otherwise they'd end up in the `main` glossary).

Alternatively, (with `glossaries-extra`) instead of using `\newacronym`, you can provide your own category and use `\newabbreviation`, which ensures it's placed in the same glossary list as the other abbreviations. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short}
```

to set the abbreviation style for the `common` category and

```
\newabbreviation[category=common]{http}{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}
```

or

```
@abbreviation{http,
  short = {HTTP},
  long = {Hypertext Transfer Protocol},
  category={common}
}
```

to define the abbreviation. Alternatively, you can instruct `bib2gls` to set the `category` field to the base name of the corresponding `.bib` file. For example, if the general abbreviations are now in `abbreviation.bib` and the common abbreviations are in `common.bib` then you can use:

```
    \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={abbreviation,common},
     category={same as base}]
```

> - I also want to have a Glossary where some of the acronyms/abbreviations appear, but not all.

You can use the `type` key to put terms into a specific glossary. You can also create an "ignored" glossary, in which you can put any entries you want to reference but don't want listed. For example, to create an ignored glossary labelled "ignored":

```
\newignoredglossary{ignored}
```

Now you can define terms to go in it. For example:

```
\newacronym[type=ignored]{p2p}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}
```

Or with `glossaries-extra`:

```
\newabbreviation[type=ignored]{p2p}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}
```

Or with `bib2gls`, the easiest way is to move the ignored abbreviations to another file, say, `ignored.bib` and use:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]% main terms
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={abbrvs,common}]% abbrvs.bib and common.bib
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={ignored},% ignored.bib
   type={ignored},% put them in the `ignored` glossary
   sort={none},% don't bother sorting
   save-locations=false% don't bother saving the locations
]
```

(If you want to keep them in the same `abbrvs.bib` file you can apply pattern matching in the selection, but that's more complicated.)

> - I also want to have an index that links to the relevant pages where
>     some of the index terms appear. It should also be possible for the
>     index to contain terms that do not appear in the glossary or acronym
>     list.

You can use the `index` package option

```
\usepackage[index]{glossaries}
```

which will create a new glossary labelled `index` and will also define the command `\newterm`, which is a shortcut for `\newglossaryentry` that defines a term without a description and uses `type=index` to add it to the `index` glossary. For example:

```
\newterm{hippo}
\newterm[plural=geese]{goose}
```

If the term contains any special characters, you'll need to use the `name` key in the optional argument and strip the special characters from the mandatory argument. For example:

```
\newterm[name={ch\^ateau},plural={ch\^ateaux}]{chateau}
```

With `bib2gls` you can use:

```
@index{hippo}
@index{goose,plural={geese}}
@index{chateau,name={ch\^ateau},plural={ch\^ateaux}}
```

(With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can use UTF-8 characters in the label but with `inputenc` you can't.)

The best style for displaying an index is [`bookindex`](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/#bookindex), which is provided by the `glossary-bookindex.sty` distributed with `glossaries-extra`. This doesn't show the description, so even with the earlier `@entry` examples, it will still only show the name and location list.

`bib2gls` has special dual entries that essentially define two linked entries. If one is referenced in the text then the other is automatically selected. Suppose I have a file called `terms.bib` that contains:

```
@index{hippo}
@index{goose,plural={geese}}
@index{chateau,name={ch\^ateau},plural={ch\^ateaux}}
@dualindexentry{duck,
 name = {duck},
 description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
}
@dualindexentry{parrot,
 name = {parrot},
 description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{debs,
  short = {DEBS},
  long = {Distributed Event-Based System}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{p2p,
 short = {P2P},
 long = {Peer-to-Peer}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{http,
 short = {HTTP},
 long = {Hypertext Transfer Protocol},
 category={common}
}
```

Then the document can be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
 index,% create 'index' glossary
 abbreviations,% create 'abbreviations' glossary
 postdot,% insert dot after descriptions
 nostyles,%don't load predefined styles
 stylemods={tree,bookindex},% load the 'tree' and 'bookindex' style packages
 style={tree}% set the default style to 'tree'
]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short} % set abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={terms},% data in terms.bib
 label-prefix={idx.},% prefix for primary entry labels
 dual-prefix={},% prefix for dual entry labels
 type=index,% put primary entries in 'index' glossary
 combine-dual-locations={primary}% merge locations and assign to primary list
]

% provide commands that work like \gls etc for the @index entries
% (that don't have a dual counterpart)
\glsxtrnewglslike{idx.}{\idx}{\idxpl}{\Idx}{\Idxpl}

\begin{document}
\section{Sample}

First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}. Next use: \gls{debs} and
\gls{p2p}.

No expansion: \gls{http}.

\section{Another Sample}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.
\Idx{hippo}, \idxpl{goose} and a \idx{chateau}.

\printunsrtglossary % main glossary
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]% list of abbreviations
\printunsrtglossary[type=index,style=bookindex] % index

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document with main glossary, list of abbreviations and index]

It's not particularly convenient to have to edit the `.bib` files to substitute `@entry` with `@dualindexentry` and `@abbreviation` with `@dualindexabbreviation`, so `bib2gls` allows aliasing with the `entry-type-aliases`, which makes `bib2gls` treat the given entry types as though they were actually defined with the aliased type:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src={entries,abbrvs,generalterms},% data in entries.bib, abbrvs.bib and generalterms.bib
 label-prefix={idx.},% prefix for primary entry labels
 dual-prefix={},% prefix for dual entry labels
 type=index,% put primary entries in 'index' glossary
 combine-dual-locations={primary},% merge locations and assign to primary list
 entry-type-aliases={
   entry=dualindexentry, % make @entry behave like @dualindexentry
   abbreviation=dualindexabbreviation % make @abbreviation behave like @dualindexabbreviation
 }
]
```

Alternatively, just use one of the indexing packages, such as `makeidx` or `imakeidx`. With `makeidx` you'll need an extra step in the build process that runs the `makeindex` application. This can be done after `makeglossaries` (and should be done after rather than before `makeglossaries` if `\index` occurs any of the glossary lists). The `imakeidx` package runs `makeindex` through the shell escape.

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\newglossaryentry{duck}{name=duck,
  description={a waterbird with webbed feet}}

\newglossaryentry{parrot}{name=parrot,
  description={mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}

\newabbreviation{debs}{DEBS}{Distributed Event-Based System}
\newabbreviation{p2p}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}

\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short}
\newabbreviation[category=common]{http}{HTTP}{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}. Next use: \gls{debs} and
\gls{p2p}.

No expansion: \gls{http}.

\chapter{Another Sample}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

Index aardvark\index{aardvark}.

\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

The `glossaries-extra` package provides a way of [automatically indexing](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:autoindex) entries so they appear both in the glossary list and the index. For example, if I add

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{common}{dualindex}{true}
```

to the preamble, then the HTTP entry (that has the `category` set to `common`) referenced on page 1 will also appear in the index. Alternatively, I can use:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{common}{indexname}{true}
```

which will instead index the page where HTTP occurs in the list of abbreviations. If I want to change the encap (how the page number is formatted in the index), then I can replace `true` with the encap value. For example:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{common}{indexname}{textbf}
```

There are various different glossary styles see, for example, the [glossaries gallery](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/#glossaries).

Comment: I have an issue with printing all my acronyms in the list of abbreviations page. None of it appears. But, the `\gls` command works and all abbreviations are substituted where needed. My command chain is `PdfLatex > makeglossaries > PdfLatex`. I have ActivePerl installed and `makeglossaries`  doesn't give any errors in TexStudio. What do you think is the issue?

Comment: @Sndn Perhaps [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233) might help.

Comment: I am sorry, but I completely lost my way in the manual. I would be grateful if you could refer me to the respective section where I can find the commands that print the description associated with the abbreviations defined by `glossaries-extra`.

Comment: Wow, this answer almost looks like a complete glossaries manual!