# What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?

Tags: glossaries, printing

I have the strange experience that from the combination

```
    \glossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
    \clearpage
    Printing acronyms
    \printglossary[type=acronym]
```

only the debug message is printed, the glossaries not.

Even, the `\printglossary` leads to hanging. At the same time, in the text
commands like `\gls{}` work as expected.  Any advice, what other package can interfere with `glossaries`? (It is part of a bigger project,
the MWE works as expected.)

---

I changed to command line version from TeXstudio. I receive the output

```
makeglossaries DSc2
makeglossaries version 2.12 (2014-01-20)
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
added glossary type 'acronym' (alg,acr,acn)
makeindex  -s "DSc2.ist" -t "DSc2.alg" -o "DSc2.acr" "DSc2.acn"
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2013] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./DSc2.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file DSc2.acn....done (9 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (36 comparisons).
Generating output file DSc2.acr....done (15 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in DSc2.acr.
Transcript written in DSc2.alg.
Warning: File 'DSc2.glo' is empty.
Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'main'?
Remember to use package option 'nomain' if you
don't want to use the main glossary.
```

What I do not understand, that if there are entries accepted, and sorted, why do I receive the warning about empty .glo file? And also, why the pdflatex hangs if I try to continue with using pdflatex again?

Comment: Do you really think we can answer this with this fragment only?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the debug message?

Comment: @Nicola Talbot I mean the message above \printglossary. It is printed, but the glossary not

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I did hope.  The fragment is only illustrating what I want to do. I do have a rather complex  macro package, with a lot of packages and expected functions. Experimenting blindly is hopeless, because of the cross-talks. I hoped someone did see similar issue (the rest of the functionality is OK, except printing) and can give a hint at least to suspect some other package.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to help without a MWE, but here are some things to check: (1) search the log file for messages starting with `! Package glossaries`, (2) check that the glossary labelled `acronym` has been defined, (3) check if `makeglossaries` (`makeindex`/`xindy`) has any warning or error messages. One other thing you could try is to change `\usepackage{glossaries}` to `\usepackage{glosaries-extra}` and replace `\setacronymstyle` with `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]`. This provides more diagnostic warnings and errors, so it might flag up something that `glossaries` misses.

Comment: If LaTeX hangs on `\printglossary`, then there's most likely something wrong in the file `DSc2.acr` or one or more of the entries defined in it. So the next thing to do is [create a MWE](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/buildingup.html) that defines and uses those 9 entries, and see if there's still a problem. Do any of those entries include commands within the definition? Are you using one of the predefined styles or have you written a custom one? (Make sure you add the style to your MWE.)

Answer (score 5):

I realise that you've managed to create a MWE and posted that as a separate question, but I thought it might help to answer your question "What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?" in a more general way that might be useful to others.

There's a Java GUI diagnostic tool called [makeglossariesgui](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeglossariesgui) that can be used to analyse a document that uses the `glossaries` package to determine possible problems. (It also has a batch mode that can be used instead of `makeglossaries` but the GUI mode has more extensive diagnostic messages.) Once it's identified the problem and you've fixed it, you can switch back to `makeglossaries`.

Although `makeglossaries` parses `makeindex`/`xindy` warning and error messages, `makeglossariesgui` additionally analyses the LaTeX messages in the `.log` file and can pick up problems that `makeglossaries` doesn't detect. There are some examples below.

## Example 1

Let's suppose I have a file called `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{Sample Acronym}

\begin{document}
\gls{sa}.

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\end{document}
```

If I do the usual

```
pdflatex test
makeglossaries test
pdflatex test
```

then `makeglossaries` issues the warning you observed:

```
Warning: File 'test.glo' is empty.
Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'main'?
Remember to use package option 'nomain' if you
don't want to use the main glossary.
```

This is a warning rather than an error in this case, but it may mask something more problematic (as in Example 3, below).

With `makeglossariesgui`, if I load `test.aux` I get the error message:

> No entries were found for glossaries 'main'

[image: image of makeglossariesgui]

The diagnostics tab provides more details:

[image: image of diagnostic tab]

This reads:

> There were no entries listed for the main glossary. Remember that you
>   must index entries for them to appear in the glossary using the
>   commands provided by the glossaries package. Entries that have been
>   defined but not indexed won't be listed. If you don't want to use this
>   glossary, add the `nomain` package option to your document. Check the
>   following:
>
> - Have you used commands like `\gls` or `\glsadd` in the document? (If you haven't, you need to add them.)
> - If you have used commands like `\glsadd` or `\glsaddall` in the preamble, have you remembered to put them *after* `\makeglossaries`
> - If you have at least version 4.24 of the glossaries package, have you used the `debug` option? (That might provide some more information
>     for me to analyse.)

If I switch to the "General Information" tab, I can see that my document has defined two glossaries: `main` and `acronym`, but there are no entries in the `main` glossary:

[image: image of general information tab]

This is why the `test.glo` file is empty and is the reason for the warning produced by `makeglossaries`. The `main` glossary is created by default, but my document hasn't defined or used any entries in that glossary. If I don't require the `main` glossary, then I need to follow the recommendation and use the `nomain` package option:

```
\usepackage[nomain,acronym]{glossaries}
```

## Example 2

This problem is more subtle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{sa}{SA}{Sample Acronym}

\begin{document}
\gls{sa}.

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\end{document}
```

In this case, if I do

```
pdflatex test
makeglossaries test
pdflatex test
```

then `makeglossaries` doesn't make any complaint, but the `test.pdf` file doesn't contain the glossary. `makeindex` is quite happy with the `test.glo` file and generates the `test.gls` file without a problem. If I switch to `glossaries-extra`, I get an error message, but with just the base `glossaries` package the message in the `.log` file is rather cryptic. However, `makeglossariesgui` can detect the problem:

[image: image of error message]

> No glossary 'acronym'

The diagnostics panel provides more information:

> It looks as though you might have done something like
>   `\printglossary[type={acronym}]`, but there's no `acronym` glossary.

## Example 3

This is another instance where `glossaries` doesn't generate an error message:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\glsaddall

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Test.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

In this case `makeglossaries` doesn't provide much help:

```
Warning: File 'test.glo' is empty.
Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'main'?
Remember to use package option 'nomain' if you
don't want to use the main glossary.
```

I'm getting the same error message as in my first example, but I've used `\glsaddall` so what's the problem? The answer is in the check list shown in `makeglossariesgui`'s diagnostic panel, which is the same as earlier, but the pertinent item here is:

> - If you have used commands like `\glsadd` or `\glsaddall` in the preamble, have you remembered to put them *after* `\makeglossaries`

If I add the `debug` package option:

```
\usepackage[debug]{glossaries}
```

I get some more information:

> It seems you have tried to index an entry in the main glossary on line
>   10, but the associated file hasn't been opened. Remember to use
>   `\makeglossaries` before commands like `\glsadd` and `\glsaddall`.
>   Details of lost indexing code:
>
> ```
> \glossaryentry{sample?\glossentry{sample}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
> ```

So the problem is that I've put `\makeglossaries` in the wrong place. It needs to go before `\glsaddall`. (This is similar to `\index` and `\makeindex`.) The `glossaries` package doesn't complain about using `\glsaddall` before `\makeglossaries` as it's perfectly reasonable to comment out `\makeglossaries` if you're working on a draft and don't want the overhead of repeatedly rebuilding the glossary whilst you're editing a complicated section of the document.

So the answer to "What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?" is: potentially a lot of things, but `makeglossariesgui` might be able to diagnose the cause.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reply. In the meantime I was forced to re-install my Linux, including TeX, and the new version solved the problem, no more hanging. So, I think that verifying versions could be a nice improvement. BTW: I am using \gls in an "innovative way". In a publication introducing an acronim is always a problem. It should be resolved at the first utilization, and the sentences sometimes change their position. Although I do not print a list, \gls solves this problem.

Comment: @Nicola what's the Java version required to run the GUI?

Comment: @Sndn Java 8 (untested on Java 9 but should work)

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a better part of a day answering the same question. Unfortunately all the good information here did not help me.

My issue was with specifically:

```
\usepackage{doc,lipsum} % provides \BibTex and \lipsum macros, for demos
```

which was in my initial source code to give examples... it prevented any calls to `\printglossaries`. Not sure what causes the issue. But I had the exact same symptoms you had, I could reference `\gls{foo}` and it would print "Foo" in the text, which is how I defined it, so I knew that was working... but the print statement was giving me nothing until I commented out that line above.

Hope that helps anyone else that has this same issue!