# \printglossaries hangs in the presence of both enumitem and beamerarticle

Tags: glossaries, enumitem, beamerarticle

Finally, I could pinpoint my question:

[What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309233/what-can-interfere-with-glossaries-to-prevent-printing)

It looks like a combined interference happens here. `\printglossaries` will hang, if you uncomment  `\usepackage{enumitem}`. What is more, glossaries works both with `beamerarticle` alone, and `enumitem` alone. The hanging occurs only if both are present.

Here goes an MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\usepackage{enumitem}  

    \usepackage{beamerarticle}  

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a sample acronym}
    \newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{another sample acronym}

    \newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

    \begin{document}
    First use: \gls{abc}, \gls{xyz}, \gls{sample}.
    Next use: \gls{abc}, \gls{xyz}.
    \glossarystyle{altlisthypergroup}
    \printglossaries
    \end{document}
```

An additional question: how (in which order) the hyperref-related packages should be invoked? (I am using internal labels, for tables, listings, figures, citations, indexes, glossary items)
Recently I have the experience that clicking on citations work OK, but clicking on acronyms not.

Comment: This example works for me with both `enumitem` and `beamerarticle` enabled, except for the warning that `\glossarystyle` is deprecated and `\setglossarystyle` should be used instead. Do you use the latest package versions?

Comment: I am not sure. I used to upgrade the setup if I have some problems. Last time I did it about 3 months ago, and using Ubuntu defaults. I'll check.

Comment: The version number will be in the `.log` file. Search for a line starting with `Package: glossaries`. Compare it with the version number [listed on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Comment: It looks like timestamp of glossaries is 2016-04-30, while that of my TeX is 2016-04-21.