# Glossary after figures

Tags: floats, glossaries

I'm currently writing an internship report and I'd like to make an appendix with every pictures of my PDF and on le last page a glossary. But I'm in trouble the glossary print before or in the middle of the figures.

I'm not really good with strict rules, most of my solutions act like "fixes"

```
    \appendix
    \part{Annexes}
\newpage
    \center

    \begin{figure}%FT17
        ...
    \end{figure}        

    %Glossary is shown here

    \begin{figure}%Usines
        ...
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}%VentesElec1
        ...
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}%VentesElec2
        ...
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}%RenaultNissan
        ...
    \end{figure}    

    \begin{figure}%COP21
        ...
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}%OrganigrammeDEAS
        ...Some Tikz Stuff...
    \end{figure}

    \printglossaries
```

Comment: I used `\begin{figure}[H]` from float package and it seem to work but I think it's a bit... harsh or disgusting (don't know the exact name)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  do you have any other text in your appendix?  (it doesn't look like it.)  you don't need to place your graphics in the figure environment; `\includegraphics` can be set by itself, and a package such as `\capt-of` used to include captions if you want them.  also, `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` or `\centering` should be used instead of `\center`; and the centering needs to be rurned off before you print your glossary.

Comment: Actually I need the figure environment because I'm using a system of `\label` (`\refstepcounter{figure}\label{#1}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}`) and `\ref`(`{\hyperref[#1]{\textsc{Figure ~\ref{#1}}}`) for each one.

Comment: are you saying you need the `figure` environment for the `\label` and `\ref`?  that's not actually true.  it's the `\caption` that identifies the `\label`, and captions provided with the `capt-of` package also support `\ref`.  (if you are creating a list of figures, that might require some additional attention.)

Comment: Ok I'll try it. But with my system the label isn't carried by the caption but by the picture. Like that it's easier when you click on a link it focus on the picture and not the caption.

Comment: in that case, more information is necessary.  a compilable example is preferable, including (especially) the `\documentclass`.  your system seems rather unusual in that respect.

Comment: I understand i'll try to give you a working small example instead of my whole code...

Comment: here it is (I have a problem with my .glo so I don't know if it work of if it's me)

Comment: You could put `\clearpage` before `\printglossaries`. That will cause a page break, but it will ensure all the floats are processed before the glossary. If you have a problem with the `.glo` file, try [`makeglossariesgui`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeglossariesgui) it has some diagnostic tools that might work out what the problem is. (See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313885) for examples.)

Answer (score 1):

here it is (I have a problem with my .glo so I don't know if it work of if it's me)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\figlabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{figure}\label{#1}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}}
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\textsc{Figure ~\ref{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\newacronym{POCM}{POCM}{Picture of My Cat}

Hello World! Here is a \gls{POCM} (\figref{fig:CAT} et \figref{fig:CAT2}).

\newpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\newpage
\begin{figure}
    \center
    \figlabel{fig:CAT}
    \fbox{Mew !}
    \caption{Picture of my cat : Mew}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \center
    \figlabel{fig:CAT2}
    \fbox{MewTwo !}
    \caption{Picture of my other cat : MewTwo}
\end{figure}

\section{Glossaire}
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you clock on the ref of a picture it focus on the picture and not the caption

Comment: this should really be added to the question, not posted as an answer.  you can always edit your own questions.  but it's a good demonstration of the problem.  i haven't tried it yet, but think the technique might work as well using `minipage` (non-floating) rather than `figure`.