# Glossaries not being printed

Tags: glossaries, sublime-text, xindy, multiple-files

The glossaries and acronyms are not showing up at `\printglossaries`. Bear with me, as I hopefully sufficiently explain the structure. I'm using Windows 7 with Sublime Text 3 and MikTeX 2.9. I installed Perl manually and added it to `path`.

I'm having my document divided into multiple files:

- main.tex (which I compile)

  ```
  \documentclass{book}
  \input{header}
  \begin{document}
  \include{chapter} 
  % ...
  \include{ending}
  \end{document}
  ```
- header.tex

  ```
  % ...
  \usepackage[xindy={language=english,codepage=utf8},%
           acronym,nopostdot,description]{glossaries}
  \makeglossaries
  \glstoctrue
  \loadglsentries{<path_to_glossaries_file>}
  % ...
  ```
- chapter.tex (multiple of those) - inside I use the `\gls{<>}`
- ending.tex

  ```
  % ...
  \printglossaries
  \printglossaries[type=\acronymtype]
  % ...
  ```

In my glossaries file, I define the elements with both `\newacronym{code}{acr}{desc}` and `\newglossaryentry{code}{name={},description={}}`

I compile the main document with a LaTeXTools script invoking:

```bash
pdflatex
bibtex
perl makeglossaries
pdflatex
pdflatex
```

always with the main name as parameter.
I get the `.acn`, `.glo` and `.xdy` files produced, just the final list is not in the `.pdf`. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to say without more information, but you could try using [this diagnostic method](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309233/what-can-interfere-with-glossaries-to-prevent-printing/313885#313885).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot What information would be useful? I'll provide it gladly ... And thanks for the tip about the diagnostic method.

Comment: Please format code blocks using indentation rather than back ticks, which should be reserved for inline code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [diagnostic method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309233/what-can-interfere-with-glossaries-to-prevent-printing/313885#313885) suggested by @NikolaTalbot . After a while I observed, that the tool adds some files automatically (`.acr`, `.gls` to name some). After some playing around, I removed the `perl` command in front of the `makeglossaries` command, and now it works!

The answer is posted, so nobody will try to find one. I know - this answer is not very informative, but I don't have a better one to offer.

Comment: @cfr I don't think `perl makeglossaries` is equivalent to `perl perl ...` on any OS. On *nix systems `makeglossaries` (without an extension) starts with `#!/usr/bin/env perl` so `bash` will automatically execute `perl` with the `makeglossaries` file, but on Windows it's `makeglossaries.exe` that executes `perl` (`makeglossaries` used as an argument doesn't assume an extension). I'm guessing that `perl makeglossaries` actually resulted in the error `Can't open perl script "makeglossaries": No such file or directory` because `perl` didn't find the file `makeglossaries` in the current directory.

Comment: @Pjanc Your answer is correct. Either omit `perl` if `makeglossaries` can automatically invoke it or use `perl` followed by the full path to the `makeglossaries` script. The first option (as in your answer) is by far the simplest.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot You are surely right.