# Glossaries Package and LaTeXTools

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, sublime-text, latextools

I used the provided answers on TEX.se a lot while writing my Bachelor Thesis but couldn´t find an answer on the following question:

How do I use the LaTeXTools build-system with the glossaries package to have a list of acronyms somewhere in my document?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,toc,shortcuts,xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries 

\newacronym{Mr}{M$_r$}{Remanence}
\newacronym{Hc}{H$_c$}{Coercivity}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
Here's a \ac{Mr} glossary entry.
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

With my MWE on Sublime Text 3 and the latest version of LaTeXTools the following output was produced:
[image: Page1 - no Acronyms section in the Content; Page2 - A well formatted acronym - but no Acronyms section at all]
Using the Terminal (OS X and TeXLive 2016) with the following commands (thesis.tex is my file)

```
xelatex thesis
makeglossaries thesis
xelatex thesis
xelatex thesis
```

the correct output was produced:
[image: Correct output produced with the terminal]

Okay now why don´t I just use the Terminal: I have way more packages that require extra commands etc. - That might be obvious

Why don´t I use a TEX-specific editor: Until now the LaTeXTools Plugin does a great job and sublime text is just one of the most convenient text-editors i´ve seen so far so I would like to keep on going with it.

I already found a question related to this which is not quite answered (I just can´t link to it because i already used the 2 links I have with my little reputation...)

Thanks in Advance for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few different ways this could be approached.

The `traditional` builder that LaTeXTools uses launches `latexmk`, so you can solve the issue the same way you would [for `latexmk`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/glossary_latexmkrc), i.e., add a `.latexmkrc` file to the directory containing your main tex document with the following contents:

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries');
sub makeglossaries {
    if ($silent) {
        system("makeglossaries -q \"$_[0]\"");
    } else{
        system("makeglossaries \"$_[0]\"");
    }
}
push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

I've based this on both the `latexmk` example file and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44316/56716) to a similar question.

Alternatively, as suggested [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325462/glossaries-not-being-printed) (I assume this is the one you were referring to), is to use the [`script` builder](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/master/README.markdown#script-builder). To do this, in your `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` file (or, better, in the `settings` section of your [Sublime project file](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html), you need to change the `builder` setting to `script` and then change the `builder_settings` block to something like this:

```
"builder_settings": {
    "osx": {
        "script_commands": [
            "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1",
            "makeglossaries",
            "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1",
            "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1"
        ]
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd choose the former of these, as the second option will run the whole script every time you build, which could take an unnecessary amount of time if you're working on a really long document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply!
I now implemented your first (and recommended) answer in my MWE - it works! 
But - and now I´ll try to figure out why - my original document is still not compiling with the error 
`TeX STOPPED: File ended while scanning use of \\newacronydescription\glspostdescription \space \glossaryentrynumbers {\relax \glsXpageXglsnumberformat 
TeX reports the error was in file:91`
Do you have any idea to that?

Comment: it was just a bracket missing... as always, isn´t it? `:D`
following your linked post i also added
`push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';`
to the `.latexmkrc` file to add the files the cleanup-ability of latexmk =)
Great Thanks again!

Comment: With LatexTools glossaries usually print fine for me. However, if I use xindy as the indexer like in `\usepackage[xindy,toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}` it won't. This fixed it for me