# Acronyms not written out in a list when using glossaries and memoir

Tags: memoir, glossaries, acronyms

I am using a style which is based on `memoir` document class. In other documents with another document class (e.g. `article`) I've used the `glossaries` package in order to write out acronyms, using `\newacronym` and `\acrlong{}` etc. However, when I've tried to copy over the same glossary file to use in the document based on `memoir` the list of abbreviations won't write out. The Acronyms in the running text written with `\acrshort{}` will however print out without any errors. Is there a way to "force" print out the list of acronyms?

EDIT: MWE:

```
 \documentclass[a4wide,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{li}{LI}{Lead Installer}
\newacronym{pm}{PM}{Project Manager}
\newacronym{nks}{NKS}{New Karolinska Solna}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoftables


\printglossary
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Abbreviations,style=index]
Above this text there should be a list of acronyms.


\section{First section}
The \acrfull{li} is responsible of notifying the \acrlong{pm} of any damages or missing equipment within two days of delivery. \acrshort{nks} for example.

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a &b  \\
        c & d 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test table}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also get the following warnings, which I believe might explain the problem at least partly:

```
    (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compat
ible-307.sty
Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2015/11/30 v4.20 (NLCT)
)
\gls@level=\count170
\@gls@tmpb=\toks34
\gls@tmplen=\skip189

Package glossaries Warning: Overriding \printglossary on input line 5207.


Package glossaries Warning: Overriding `theglossary' environment on input line 
5848.
```

[image: Running the code above yields the following result]

Comment: Full minimal example please. Did you remember to load the `glossaries` package in your `memoir` document? `memoir` has some glossary capabilities, but not as extensive as the `glossaries` package, and the two are not 100% compatible.

Comment: Those two warnings are really just information messages to let you know that `glossaries` is overriding some other glossary provider (`memoir` in this case) and in this case are unlikely to point to the problem as `glossaries` usually works okay with `memoir`. (The warnings can be suppressed with the package option `noredefwarn`.) Are there any error messages in the `makeindex`/`xindy` transcript? [Try this diagnostic tool](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313885) which analyses the transcript for known problems.

Comment: I have now added a MWE and picture of the output I get. @daleif

Comment: When I compile your mwe (using TeXLive 2016) I get a 3 page doc, where the list of abbreviations is at the top of page 3. Note that several compilations were needed (I used `latexmk -pdf` to compile it)

Comment: @daleif I tried to run it on locally instead of ShareLatex and now it works - so it seems like the problem was on Share Latex rather than in my code. Weird that I got it to work in one document on ShareLatex and not the other though.... Thank you anyways - now I know it works!

Comment: Remember, sharelatex often use older code, thus newer features might not work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue seemed to be a temporary problem of the online compiler