# Categorize Acronyms based on type

Tags: acronyms

Consider the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-acro.tex}

%%% Type: institute
\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{Awesome Best College}
%%% Type: journal
\newacronym{ijk}{IJK}{International Journal of Karaoke}
%%% Type: conference
\newacronym{cde}{CDE}{Conference on Dual Eternity}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,smallcaps]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries[\acronymtype]{\jobname-acro}
\makenoidxglossaries 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,]  

\section{Some examples}
Some Text \gls{abc} and \gls{cde} also \gls{ijk}
\end{document}
```

The acronyms are printed together:

[image]

What I want is, acronyms will be categorized into three classes, something like:

[image]

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes (for indexing)

Answer (score 1):

The `glossaries` package does support hierarchical styles. These can span over multiple levels, however, for your case 2 are sufficient (level 0 and 1). You might want to have a look at the [manual](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf), it gives a list of the styles capabilities (2017-06-29: Chapter 15, page 199).

If you have selected a style to your liking, I'd suggest to define a new command used to add the entries, as shown below. I used this to distinguish symbols (roman, greek, math, ...), but in the end it doesn't really matter. The important part is the `parent=roman` option, and - for you - the `type=acronym` option.

What you probably don't need is the `symbol` and `unit` stuff, that is just an extention for my glossary.

```
\newglossaryentry{roman}{name={Roman Symbols}, description={\glspar}, type=symbols, sort=10}
\newcommand{\newromansymbol}[5][]{
    % create the glossary entry in the greek category
    \newglossaryentry{symb:#2}{
        name={#2},
        symbol={\ensuremath{#3}},
        description={#4},
        unit={#5},
        type=symbols,
        parent=roman,
        #1
    }
}
\newromansymbol[sort=S2]{source-term}{S}{Source or sink term (in general, $S$, or for a defined property \gls{symb:phi} as $S_\phi$)}{\si{\au}}
\newromansymbol[sort=D]{diffusion}{D}{Diffusion coefficient}{\si{\square\metre\per\second}}
\newromansymbol[sort=u1]{velocity}{\vect{u}}{Velocity}{\si{\metre\per\second}}
\newromansymbol[sort=v]{fluid-velocity}{v}{Fluid velocity}{\si{\metre\per\second}}
```

If no existing style does what you want you can quite easily modify one. Compare the Question *[glossaries: How to customize list of symbols with additional column for units?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269571/100384)* for a general example.

Comment: Regarding the `parent` key, if used the MWE would need to change from using `\makenoidxglossaries`/`\printnoidxglossary` to `\makeglossaries`/`\printglossary`. [Since 'Option 1' isn't suitable for hierarchical entries](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot For some unknown reason `\makeglossaries`/`\printglossary` doesn't print the glossaries for me.

Comment: @Timm Can you give a complete MWE? I tried copy-pasting your snippet, but did something wrong (got errors).

Comment: @pushpen.paul Did you [run `makeglossaries`](http://latex.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms#makeglossaries) (or `makeglossaries-lite`) when you built the document? Alternatively try the `automake` package option. See also [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233).