# Glossary just partially filled

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}`
to build my acronym list and glossary.
I struggling because I don't understand why they are only partially filled.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[ansinew,utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\AtBeginDocument{
  \addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-0.5\baselineskip}
  \addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-0.5\baselineskip}
}
\bibliographystyle{harward}
\addto\captionsenglish{
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}


\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\footnotesize}
\makeglossaries 

\newglossaryentry{bigdata}{
        name=Big Data,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{cluster}{
        name=Cluster,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{clustercomputing}{
        name=Cluster computing,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{cloudcomputing}{
        name=Cloud computing,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{gridcomputing}{
        name=Grid computing,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{healthcare}{
        name=Healthcare,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{wearables}{
        name=Wearables,
        description={glossario}}        

\newglossaryentry{semanticweb}{
        name=Semantic web,
        description={glossario}}   

\newglossaryentry{veracity}{
        name=Veracity,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{timeliness}{
        name=Timeliness,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{opensource}{
        name=Open source,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{microbatching}{
        name=Micro batching,
        description={glossario}}

\newglossaryentry{iot}{
        name=Internet of Things,
        description={glossario}}

\newacronym{rt}{RT}{Real Time}
\newacronym{ssg}{SSG}{Slot Sharing Group}
\newacronym{it}{IT}{Innovation Technology}
\newacronym{us}{US}{United States}
\newacronym{uk}{UK}{United Kingdom}
\newacronym{ecg}{ECG}{Electrocardiography}
\newacronym{rdd}{RDD}{Resilient Distributed Dataset}
\newacronym{cql}{CQL}{Cassandra Query Language}
\newacronym{rdf}{RDF}{Resource Description Framework}
\newacronym{iri}{IRI}{Internationalized Resource Identifier}
\newacronym{url}{URL}{Uniform Resource Locator}
\newacronym{dsms}{DSMS}{Data Stream Management System}
\newacronym{cep}{CEP}{Complex Event Processing}
\newacronym{dbms}{DBMS}{DataBase Management System}
\newacronym{rdbms}{RDBMS}{Relational DataBase Management System}
\newacronym{r2rml}{R2RML}{RDB to RDF Mapping Language}

\begin{document} 

...
...
...

\glsaddall
\glsaddallunused
\glossarystyle{list}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]
\glossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary[title= Glossary of Terms, type=main, nonumberlist]

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
...
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

but the output is:

[image: acronym list]
[image: glossary]

How can I fix it?

EDIT::::

I report also text of

.acl

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./postfatos.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file postfatos.acn....done (3 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (5 comparisons).
Generating output file postfatos.acr....done (12 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in postfatos.acr.
Transcript written in postfatos.alg.
```

.glg

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./postfatos.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file postfatos.glo....done (8 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (25 comparisons).
Generating output file postfatos.gls....done (25 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in postfatos.gls.
Transcript written in postfatos.glg.
```

.gls

```
\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}\glossarypreamble
\begin{theglossary}\glossaryheader
\glsgroupheading{B}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossentry{bigdata}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{C}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossentry{cloudcomputing}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}%
\glossentry{cluster}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}%
\glossentry{clustercomputing}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{H}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossentry{healthcare}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{S}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossentry{semanticweb}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{V}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossentry{veracity}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}\glsgroupskip
\glsgroupheading{W}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossentry{wearables}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1}}}%
\end{theglossary}\glossarypostamble
```

.acn and .glo contains all the entry I need, instead .acr and .gls contains only the entry which appear in pdf.

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me, but some tips: don't use both `\glsaddall` and `\glsaddallunused` (one or the other but not both), and move `hyperref` and `glossaries-extra` to the end of the `\usepackage` list. (They should always be loaded last.) Check the transcript files (`.glg` and `.alg`) for messages.

Comment: it doesn't work anyway.
I checked .glg and .alg files but there are no errors and 0 entries rejected.
I noted that also moving the order of the entries nothing changes. It is like stuck!

Comment: There's a debugging tool described in my answer to [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233) Perhaps that might help. Other things to check: version numbers of [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) and [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), and check the `.glo` and `.acn` files to make sure that all entries have been added to them.

Comment: Did you rerun `makeglossaries` and LaTeX after editing your `.tex` file?

Comment: If you means If I clicked on "Typeset" button yes I did it.

Comment: That depends on what the "Typeset" button does. If it only runs (pdf)latex then the glossary files won't be rebuilt.