# Glossaries not printing to yet an other latex newb

Tags: glossaries, texmaker

So let me begin by saying that I've seen that this is a very common issue, especially with texmaker on windows, and there are a lot of solutions out there, but I've tried all the ones that I found and they either didn't work or I couldn't understand them.

My code looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\loadglsentries{acronyms}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Symbols and Abbreviations}\label{chapter:symbols and abbreviations}
\setglossarystyle{long}
\printglossary[title=Symbols]
\setglossarystyle{long}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abbreviations]

A whole bunch of text from my thesis with the following abbreviations and symbols, \acrfull{nf}, \acrlong{efr}, \gls{z}.

\end{document}
```

In my `acronyms.tex` file I have the following (plus a lot more)

```
\newacronym{nf}{NF}{Near Focus}
\newacronym{efr}{EFR}{Extra Focal Radiation}
\newglossaryentry{z}        {name={\ensuremath{z}},     description={\tabto{1cm}[$mm$] \tabto{4cm} top surface of shutters and fs distance}}
```

As most people I've read about this runs without the glossaries being printed.

I've tried changing some line in the Xindy file but I found it already changed.
I tried changing the commands to `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries` or `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries` but nope.
I tried making the `makeglossaries %` user command in texmaker but I get the following error when running it:

```
Process started

makeglossaries

: The script engine could not be found. makeglossaries: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"

Process exited with error(s)
```

I've read among other solution something about installing `Perl` and manually adding it to some path but I don't really know what to do specifically and I have no clue if it will actually solve the problem.

If somebody could help clear out some of this and point me in the right direction it would be of great help, I've already spent a couple of hours on this stuff.
Thank you all!

Comment: It looks like you don't have Perl installed. You could try replacing the script engine `makeglossaries %` with `makeglossaries-lite %` although installing Perl so that you can run `makeglossaries` instead is better. Related: [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158796). The option is to add `automake` to the list of `glossaries` package options.

Comment: Installing Perl did allow the `makeglossaries` command to work but now when I run pdfLatex I get a whole bunch of errors that I can't even copy and paste here for some reason. While replacing with `makeglossaries-lite %` gives me the error `Error : could not start the command : makeglossaries-lite "test"`. Does that mean anything to you?  
ps. test is the name of my file.

Comment: I don't know why `makeglossaries-lite` isn't working. I don't have Windows to test it on. There's some debugging methods for `glossaries` described in my answer to [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233)

Comment: That GUI diagnostic tool you made is a life saver! Took some time but I managed to make the code work. Thanks!