# How to use bib2gls in TexLive on a mac?

Tags: glossaries-extra

I am trying to use the glossaries-extra package with an .bib file which contains all my abbreviations, glossary entries, and symbols.

There is the bib2gls package/tool out there, but, unfortunately, I am unable to use the bib2gls on my mac with TeX Live 2017 and Java 8 update 144.

Can anyone help my how to run bib2gls on my mac?

I used the example from here: [bib2gls example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287080/best-solution-for-acronyms-abbreviations-glossary-and-index)

The `entries.bib` file is like in the bib2gls manual:

```
@entry{duck,
name = {duck},
description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}}

@entry{parrot,
name = {parrot},
description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}}
```

A working example with the filename `myDoc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entries}]

\begin{document}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

The build process according bib2gls manual is now:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

But I don't know how to run `bib2gls myDoc`.

Best regards

Markus

Comment: `bib2gls` is a command line tool. If you build your documents by clicking on a button/menu item you need to say what editor you're using (for example, TeXworks, TeXstudio).