# Add word to abbreviation list

Tags: lists

How is used

```
\chapwithtoc
```

that write a list of abbriviations? How to add a word to this list? Thank you.

Comment: Please do not only throw code snippets at us! Explain your issue with a complete compilable code.  BTW looking on your reputation you should know that ...

Comment: That's not a standard command. What class are you using?

Comment: I use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}`
This is in makro: `\def\chapwithtoc#1{
\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}` or it is about number of chapter?

Comment: That just creates an unnumbered chapter that's added to the table of contents. You could write `\chapwithtoc{Abbreviations}\begin{description}\item[EX] Example Abbreviation\end{description}` but if you want an automated method, try [Best solution for acronyms, abbreviations, glossary and index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287080).