# How to make a list of abbreviations, acronyms, symbols, glossary and index with the glossaries package?

Tags: packages, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to make a list of abbreviation, list of acronyms, list of symbols, glossary and index using the glossaries package as following order:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[linkcolor=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,acronym,abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
%Abreviations
\newabbreviation{p}{p.}{page}
\newabbreviation{s}{s.}{sheet}
\newabbreviation{jan}{jan.}{January}
\newabbreviation{etal}{et al.}{et al}
\newabbreviation{v}{v.}{volume}
%Acronyms
\newacronym{MPE}{MPE}{Modelo Padrão Estendido}
\newacronym{UFMA}{UFMA}{Universidade Federal do Maranhão}
\newacronym{BPS}{BPS}{Bogomol'ny-Prassad-Somefeld}
\newacronym{MCS}{MSC}{Maxwell-Chern-Simons}
%Symbols
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={the set that does not contain any element}]{emptyset}{\ensuremath{\emptyset}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of natural numbers}]{N}{\ensuremath{\mathds{N}}}    
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of integer numbers}]{Z}{\ensuremath{\mathds{Z}}}
%Glossary
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={example},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{cow}{name={cow},plural={cows},description={an adult female of any bovine animal.}} 
\newglossaryentry{par}{name={paragraph},description={distinct section of a piece of writing}}
%index
\index{BPS}
\index{MCS}
\index{Natural numbers}
\index{cow}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter%
%
\printglossary[type=acronym,title=List of Acronyms]
\printglossary[type=abbreviations,title=List of Abreviation]
\printglossary[type=symbols,title=List of Symbols]%
%
\tableofcontents%
%
\mainmatter%
%
\chapter{Acronyms}
 First use: \gls{MPE}. Second use: \gls{MPE}.

 First use: \gls{UFMA}. Second use: \gls{UFMA}.

 First use: \gls{BPS}. Second use: \gls{BPS}.

 First use: \gls{MCS}. Second use: \gls{MCS}.

 \gls{ex}, \gls{cow} and \gls{par}.

\index{BPS}, \index{MCS}, \index{N} and \index{cow}
\chapter{Abreviations}
First use: \gls{p}. Second use: \gls{p}.

First use: \gls{s}. Second use: \gls{s}.

First use: \gls{jan}. Second use: \gls{jan}.

First use: \gls{etal}. Second use: \gls{etal}.

First use: \gls{v}. Second use: \gls{v}.

\gls{ex}, \gls{cow} and \gls{par}
\chapter{Symbols}
\gls{emptyset}

\gls{N}

\gls{Z}

\gls{ex}, \gls{cow} and \gls{par}

\backmatter
\printglossary[type=main,title=Glossary]
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see no one has answered and I am not qualified to tell how difficult a solution may be. There is a good tutorial by @nicola-talbot at this link that may help https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287128/170109 If you work out a good solution from that you can of course answer your own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just a couple of minor changes this eventually compiled as 13 pages (so not included here), I will bow to others who provide better answers, explaining any other changes required (and remove my answer if bettered). My aim was just to find the basic errors which stopped the numerous runs which were very simply two accented characters.

Compiled in TeXworks with

pdfLaTeX  filename
makeglossaries  filename
pdfLaTeX  filename

Here are the contents, If its not as expected then please amend your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[linkcolor=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[symbols,acronyms,abbreviations,automake]{glossaries-extra}
% CHANGED **acronym to acronyms** & added automake to assist but would probably compile without  

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
%Abreviations
\newabbreviation{p}{p.}{page}
\newabbreviation{s}{s.}{sheet}
\newabbreviation{jan}{jan.}{January}
\newabbreviation{etal}{et al.}{et al}
\newabbreviation{v}{v.}{volume}

%Acronyms
\newacronym{MPE}{MPE}{Modelo Padr\~{a}o Estendido} % changed the accent to \~{a}
\newacronym{UFMA}{UFMA}{Universidade Federal do Maranh\~{a}o}  % changed the accent to \~{a}

\newacronym{BPS}{BPS}{Bogomol'ny-Prassad-Somefeld}
\newacronym{MCS}{MSC}{Maxwell-Chern-Simons}
%Symbols
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={the set that does not contain any element}]{emptyset}{\ensuremath{\emptyset}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of natural numbers}]{N}{\ensuremath{\mathds{N}}}    
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={set of integer numbers}]{Z}{\ensuremath{\mathds{Z}}}
%Glossary
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={example},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{cow}{name={cow},plural={cows},description={an adult female of any bovine animal.}} 
\newglossaryentry{par}{name={paragraph},description={distinct section of a piece of writing}}
%index
\index{BPS}
\index{MCS}
\index{Natural numbers}
\index{cow}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter%
%
\printglossary[type=acronym,title=List of Acronyms]
%
\printglossary[type=abbreviations,title=List of Abreviation] % <-- should this be Abbreviations (double bb & Plural)
%
\printglossary[type=symbols,title=List of Symbols]%
%
\tableofcontents%
%
\mainmatter%
%
\chapter{Acronyms}
 First use: \gls{MPE}. Second use: \gls{MPE}.

 First use: \gls{UFMA}. Second use: \gls{UFMA}.

 First use: \gls{BPS}. Second use: \gls{BPS}.

 First use: \gls{MCS}. Second use: \gls{MCS}.

 \gls{ex}, \gls{cow} and \gls{par}.

\index{BPS}, \index{MCS}, \index{N} and \index{cow}
\chapter{Abreviations}
First use: \gls{p}. Second use: \gls{p}.

First use: \gls{s}. Second use: \gls{s}.

First use: \gls{jan}. Second use: \gls{jan}.

First use: \gls{etal}. Second use: \gls{etal}.

First use: \gls{v}. Second use: \gls{v}.

\gls{ex}, \gls{cow} and \gls{par}
\chapter{Symbols}
\gls{emptyset}

\gls{N}

\gls{Z}

\gls{ex}, \gls{cow} and \gls{par}

\backmatter
\printglossary[type=main,title=Glossary]
\printindex
\end{document}
```