# glossaries-extra package cyrillic characters issues in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, cyrillic, glossaries-extra

When I use glossaries-extra with cyrillic characters in LuaLaTeX, I get two issues:

1. different  line spacing in glossary and abbreviation;
2. incorrect sorting in the index for Cyrillic words.

Please refer to the below MWE, for an example, which compiles to the document provided at the end of this question.

I am use MikTex in  Windows 10 with option **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"**.
In TexStudio use this command: **bib2gls.exe -g --tex-encoding utf-8 %** .

How might I be able to resolve this issues?

Thanks so mach.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf-8
% !TeX spellcheck = ru_RU
%============================================================================================
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}  %% устанавливает главный язык документа
\setotherlanguage{english}                     %% устанавливает второй язык документа
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic} %% задаёт свойства шрифтов по умолчанию
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}                  %% задаёт основной шрифт документа
\setsansfont{Arial}                            %% задаёт шрифт без засечек
\setmonofont{Courier New}                      %% задаёт моноширинный шрифт
%==========================================================
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{kerning=russian}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%==========================================================
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
index,% create 'index' glossary
abbreviations,% create 'abbreviations' glossary
postdot,% insert dot after descriptions
nostyles,%don't load predefined styles
stylemods={tree,bookindex},% load the 'tree' and 'bookindex' style packages
style={tree}% set the default style to 'tree'
]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short} % set abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
src={terms},% data in terms.bib
label-prefix={idx.},% prefix for primary entry labels
dual-prefix={},% prefix for dual entry labels
type=index,% put primary entries in 'index' glossary
combine-dual-locations={primary}% merge locations and assign to primary list
]


% provide commands that work like \gls etc for the @index entries
% (that don't have a dual counterpart)
\glsxtrnewglslike{idx.}{\idx}{\idxpl}{\Idx}{\Idxpl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{terms.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8 
@index{hippo}
@index{ЛПР}
@index{goose,plural={geese}}
@index{chateau,name={ch\^ateau},plural={ch\^ateaux}}
@dualindexentry{duck,
    name = {duck},
    description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
}
@dualindexentry{whale,
    name = {кит},
    description = {большая рыба}
}
@dualindexentry{shark,
    name = {акула},
    description = {хищная рыба}
}
@dualindexentry{parrot,
    name = {parrot},
    description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{debs,
    short = {DEBS},
    long = {Distributed Event-Based System}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{p2p,
    short = {P2P},
    long = {Peer-to-Peer}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{http,
    short = {HTTP},
    long = {Hypertext Transfer Protocol},
    category={common}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{xml,
    short = {XML},
    long = {eXtensible Markup Language}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{db,
    short = {БД},
    long = {База данных}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{yamao,
    short = {ЯМАО},
    long = {Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \section{Sample}
    
    First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}.\\
    \textbf{My test:} \gls{xml}, \gls{yamao}, \gls{db}.

    Next use: \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}.\\
    \textbf{My test:} \gls{xml}, \gls{yamao}, \gls{db}.
    
    No expansion: \gls{http}.
    
    \section{Another Sample}
    
    A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot} and \gls{whale} and \gls{shark}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.
    \Idx{hippo}, \idxpl{goose} and a \idx{chateau}.
    
    Тут написано про \idx{ЛПР}.
    
    \printunsrtglossary % main glossary
    \printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]% list of abbreviations
    
    \newpage
    \printunsrtglossary[type=index, style=bookindex, title=Index] % index
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I run OK (TeXLive 2022, Windows): no problems with line-spacing, and sorting in Index is Unicode: `кит` comes after `parrot` because Cyrillic is after Latin (also, capital letters before small letters). Perhaps I do not understand what the expected result should be.

Comment: Sorting: "If the `sort` field is missing the default is obtained from the `name` field" (texdoc bib2gls).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287080/best-solution-for-acronyms-abbreviations-glossary-and-index/287128#287128

Comment: Thanks, @Cicada. Please, add a picture of your result. Sorting issue in Index only cyrillic words (bottom example in the picture). I used the example from the link you provided as a basis.

Comment: bib2gls.exe -g <---- Problems appear due to this option "-g".

Comment: I see what you mean now. It is related to grouping and sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With grouping in the index, the simplest set-up is to auto-group on case-insensitive letters:

```
group={auto},
sort={letter-nocase},
```

[image: gloss]

[image: abbrev]

[image: index]

The package can do much more powerful output than that, though. For me, I will have to read the manual fully and see the examples.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{terms.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8 
@index{hippo}
@index{cake}
@index{КИТ,name={КИТ}}
@index{ЛПР}
@index{goose,plural={geese}}
@index{chateau,name={ch\^ateau},plural={ch\^ateaux}}
@dualindexentry{duck,
    name = {duck},
    description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
}
@dualindexentry{кит2,
    name = {кит2},
    description = {большая рыба2}
}
@dualindexentry{whale,
    name = {кит},
    description = {большая рыба}
}
@dualindexentry{shark,
    name = {акула},
    description = {хищная рыба}
}
@dualindexentry{parrot,
    name = {parrot},
    description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{debs,
    short = {DEBS},
    long = {Distributed Event-Based System}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{p2p,
    short = {P2P},
    long = {Peer-to-Peer}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{http,
    short = {HTTP},
    long = {Hypertext Transfer Protocol},
    category={common}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{xml,
    short = {XML},
    long = {eXtensible Markup Language}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{db,
    short = {БД},
    long = {База данных}
}
@dualindexabbreviation{yamao,
    short = {ЯМАО},
    long = {Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ}
}
\end{filecontents}


%============================================================================================
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}  %% устанавливает главный язык документа
\setotherlanguage{english}                     %% устанавливает второй язык документа
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic} %% задаёт свойства шрифтов по умолчанию
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}                  %% задаёт основной шрифт документа
\setsansfont{Arial}                            %% задаёт шрифт без засечек
\setmonofont{Courier New}                      %% задаёт моноширинный шрифт
%==========================================================
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{kerning=russian}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%==========================================================
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
index,% create 'index' glossary
abbreviations,% create 'abbreviations' glossary
postdot,% insert dot after descriptions
nostyles,%don't load predefined styles
stylemods={tree,bookindex},% load the 'tree' and 'bookindex' style packages
style={tree},% set the default style to 'tree'
]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short} % set abbreviation style before \GlsXtrLoadResources

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
src={terms},% data in terms.bib
%dual-sort={letter-nocase},
label-prefix={idx.},% prefix for primary entry labels
dual-prefix={},% prefix for dual entry labels
type=index,% put primary entries in 'index' glossary
combine-dual-locations={primary},% merge locations and assign to primary list
group={auto},
sort={letter-nocase},
%category={same as entry},
]


% provide commands that work like \gls etc for the @index entries
% (that don't have a dual counterpart)
\glsxtrnewglslike{idx.}{\idx}{\idxpl}{\Idx}{\Idxpl}
%\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \section{Sample}
    
    First use \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}.\\
    \textbf{My test:} \gls{xml}, \gls{yamao}, \gls{db}.

    Next use: \gls{debs} and \gls{p2p}.\\
    \textbf{My test:} \gls{xml}, \gls{yamao}, \gls{db}.
    
    No expansion: \gls{http}.
    
    \section{Another Sample}
    
    A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot} and \gls{whale} and \gls{shark}. Lots of \glspl{duck}.
    \Idx{hippo}, \idxpl{goose} and a \idx{chateau}.
    
    Тут написано про \idx{ЛПР}.
    
        \newpage
        \printunsrtglossary % main glossary
    \newpage
        \printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]% list of abbreviations
    
    \newpage
    \printunsrtglossary[type=index, style=bookindex, title=Index] % index
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so mach, @Cicada.